# DynamoDB update using NODEjs: Syntax error token: "_", near: ", _geoloc"

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Each object in my dynamoDB table looks something like

```
{
  _geoloc: {lat: 123, lng: 456},
  name: 'abc',
  city: 'belarus',
  id: 'unique1'
}
```

I have the following update expression:

```
const params = {
    TableName: CONFIG.dynamoDB.tableName,
    Key:{
      "id": location.id.toString()
    },
    UpdateExpression: "set city=:c, _geoloc=:g",
    ExpressionAttributeValues:{
      ":c": location.address.city,
      ":g": geoCodes
    },
    ReturnValues:"UPDATED_NEW"
  };
```

DynamoDB throws the following error:

```
ValidationException: Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: "_", near: ", _geoloc"
    at Request.extractError (/Users/mv/pcode/meeting-finder-kinesis-consumer/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:48:27)
```

As far as I know.. _ is a valid character to have in a name

any suggestions how I can fix this ?

Answer (score 6):

Agreed, the attribute name can contain underscore. However, in this case, you need to define a placeholder for attribute name in the update expression and use Expression Attribute Name to define the actual attribute name (as it contains special characters) for the placeholder.

```
"ExpressionAttributeNames" : "#geoloc = _geoloc"
```

Also, just replace the _geoloc on update expression with #geoloc.

This should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error as mentioned in question. In my case I was using the CLI. Took a while to figure out syntax so hopefully this is helpful.

I had a column with an underscore `_ct` which caused the ValidationException

The resulting `update-item` command was:

```
aws dynamodb update-item \
    --table-name myTable \
    --key '{ "pk": { "S": "myPrimarykey" },"sk": { "S": "mySortkey" } }' \
    --update-expression "SET #ct = :ct" \
    --expression-attribute-values file://values.json \
    --expression-attribute-names '{"#ct":"_ct"}'
```

values.json -->

```
{
    ":ct": {
      "S": "2022-12-07T11:00:10.881Z"
    }
  }
```